# Server error handling (404, 403 etc.) in plotly dash

Tags: python, http, flask, plotly-dash, flask-login

I am running a dash app with authentication via flask-login and it has come up during some security tests that the app doesn't produce the correct errors when authentication and/or permission checks fail.

Whan I have done so far is simply returning '403' within the callback if the permission check fails, but of course dash will modify these to suit its own API.

So instead of an appropriate error I get either a 200 with a JSON response like this: `{"response": {"props": {"displayed": "403"}}}`, or I get a 500 if the Dash API can't process the '403' string.

Comment: Here's a related discussion you might find interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59568510/320399

Answer (score 1):

After some research about flask, the most appropriate solution appears to be to use flask's Response to send the server error code, and then do whatever you find appropriate in the callback, for example:

```py
if not current_user.authenticated:
    Response('Not permitted', 403)
    return html.Div('Not permitted')
```

or

```py
if not current_user.authenticated:
    Response('Not permitted', 403)
    raise PreventUpdate
```