# Dash suppress_callback_exceptions not working

Tags: python, html, plotly-dash, suppress-warnings

Here is how I implement it in my code. I have tried each way individually and using all of them as uncommented lines of code. No matter the combination of methods I use, I still have to manually turn suppress errors once my dashboard loads.

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
app.title = 'TEST'

app.config['suppress_callback_exceptions'] = True
app.config.suppress_callback_exceptions = True
```

I have also tried (without any luck):

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets,
                suppress_callback_exceptions = True)
```

and

```
import sys
class HaltCallback(Exception):
    pass

@app.server.errorhandler(HaltCallback)
def handle_error(error):
    print(error, file=sys.stderr)
    return ('', 204)
```

Are there any other possible ways I can try to suppress the callback exceptions? I'm making a dashboard for my boss, so I'd really like automate the error suppression upon loading it.

Answer (score 16):

**For any future viewers**: This bug was fixed some time after the question was posted.

[The oldest answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59569568) does *technically* fix it, but it will also disable real callback errors along the way (that aren't fired on the start). If you are looking for where to put `suppress_callback_exceptions=True`, put it in the app declaration itself, like:
`app = dash.Dash( ... , suppress_callback_exceptions=True)`.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on dash version 1.20.0

Answer (score 7):

Figured it out

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False,dev_tools_ui=False,dev_tools_props_check=False)
```

Needed to just disable dev_tools_ui on the actual webpage

Comment: This issue was bugging me for hours! THANK YOU :D

Answer (score 3):

When I ran into this problem, I had to place the config statement immediately after the app creation to suppress the errors. For example:

```
app=dash.Dash(__name__)
app.config.suppress_callback_exceptions=True
```

Found my answer [here](https://medium.com/@drimik99/a-python-programmers-guide-to-dashboarding-part-2-5de0fa8179f0) and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete the answers given:

`app = dash.Dash( ... , suppress_callback_exceptions=True)` works well for normal callbacks. If you have a `long_callback` you also need to provide a `validation_layout` that contains all of the components referenced by callbacks in the app and set the `prevent_initial_call=True` argument of `app.long_callback`.

For more information and examples please refer to the official documentation of long callbacks:
https://dash.plotly.com/long-callbacks#limitations